# Trigger function when element in view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll to create a one pager and would like to trigger a function (a modal lightbox) when scrolling to a specific section.

I've tried a few different scripts ([appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear), [waypoint](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints)) but so far have come up trumps. Not sure if it's got to do with the fact that onepage scroll isn't actually scrolling but moving the section into the viewpoint.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of what you're seeing?

Comment: This [demo](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) should give you a pretty good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the callbacks the plugin provides.

Also, if you want to change for a more complete plugin such as [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), there you have the option [`scrollBar`](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html) than when set to `true` will allow plugins such as *waypoint* or *appear* to work as expected.

The reason for it is detailed in [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frecuently-Answered-Questions#parallax-doesnt-work-with-fullpagejs):

> Parallax, **as well as many other plugins which depends on the
>   scrolling of the site**, listens the scrollTop property of javascript.
>   fullPage.js doesn't actually scroll the site but it changes the top or
>   translate3d property of the site. Only when using the fullPage.js
>   option scrollBar:true or autoScrolling:false it will actually scroll
>   the site in a way it is accessible for the scrollTop property.

The same principle is applied to *onepage-scroll* but the difference is that fullPage.js provides a way to deal with it (`scrollBar:true`) and *onepage-scroll* doesn't.